# how to change zeros to ones in 2-D array?

Tags: python

hello everyone i am a beginner in python, i using turtle to built an algorithm to insert set of  small rectangles inside big rectangle(bin packing problem (bottom left fill strategy)), the inserting process code as follow; where (X,Y are arrays hold width and height of small rectangles respectively and a,b are the width and height of big rectangle):

```
a=5
b=5
X=[2]
Y=[2]
Empty = np.zeros((b, a))
for i in range(len(X)):
    colours = ["Green", "blue", "black", "yellow", "purple", "pink", "blue", "yellow"]
    t.color(colours[i])
    t.begin_fill()
    t.pendown()
    for j in range(2):
        t.speed(0)
        t.fd(X[i])
        t.lt(90)
        t.fd(Y[i])
        t.lt(90)
    t.end_fill()
    t.penup()
    for n in range((Y[i])):
        for k in range(X[i]):
            Empty[n][k] = 1
```

during the coding i a zeros define an array called (Empty) refer to the big rectangle, when the small rectangle inserted the zeros values change to ones in order to diagnoses the loaded and empty areas, but its not effective idea.The out put of Empty is:

```
[[1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

The array must change the bottom left position values, see below:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]
 [1. 1. 0. 0. 0.]]
```

If anybody have resolved to my array problem or have another idea to change zeros to ones without uses for loop that is will be great. Thank you.

Comment: Just confirming – the bottom matrix is what you're expecting as output, but the top matrix is what you currently have, right?

Comment: yes.. Exactly  the bottom matrix is what I am  expecting as output, but the top matrix is what I currently have.

Comment: Cool. That was the assumption I made in my solution below. Let me know if it doesn't pan-out and I'll revise. 

Answer (score 0):

First – welcome to Python!  (And maybe even programming. )

Assuming that the bottom matrix is your intended result, you're quite close! You have an indexing error (super common, especially in early days). Arrays in Python (and many other languages) always start from the top-left. To achieve the results you're looking for, you need to use the known number of `rows` of `Empty`, as follows:

```py
X = [2]
Y = [2]

shape = (5, 5)
Empty = np.zeros(shape)

for i in range(len(X)):
    # ... I'm ignoring the Turtle code for brevity, you'll need to add it back
    for row in range(X[i]):
        for col in range(Y[i]):
            Empty[len(Empty) - row - 1, col] = 1
```

After these changes, you should now see an array that looks like the following:

```py
array([[0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [0., 0., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.],
       [1., 1., 0., 0., 0.]])
```

---

**Readability / performance tip:** You can condense your nested `(row, col)` for-loop into a single line by using `itertools`, it's in the standard library, so you don't need to install anything.

Here's how you'd do that.

```py
from itertools import product  # this is the Cartesian product
X = [2]
Y = [2]

shape = (5, 5)
Empty = np.zeros(shape)

for i in range(len(X)):
    # ... I'm ignoring the Turtle code for brevity, you'll need to add it back
    for row, col in product(range(X[i]), range(Y[i]):
        Empty[len(Empty) - row - 1, col] = 1
```

`itertools.product` one of many tools in Python that lets you make Python more predictable, thus improving performance. It also helps you adhere to [Pep 20, "The Zen of Python"](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0020/#id2), which pushes the idea of "Flat is better than nested."